# How, in Android, using relative layout, display a view (example textview) under another one, but only if has text - i.e. not empty

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Let's say that, using a relative layout, on first row I display a date text field, then next to it an item textview, then I want to display below the item textview, a description textview, but only if that description is not empty. Is there a "conditional" property we can use? How could we do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no such conditional properties for any framework Views.

A simple way to do this is to do it in your Java code like so:

```
String description;
TextView descriptionView;

if (TextUtils.isEmpty(description)) {
    descriptionView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    descriptionView.setText(description);
    descriptionView.setVisibility(View.VISILBE);
}
```

You can position the TextView wherever you would want it to be in your layout when there is content to display, and simply hide it when there is no content to display.

Comment: condition is interchanged! When description is empty, the view should be made GONE and vice versa

Comment: Actually, using a custom SimpleAdapter, and overriding the getView method, you only need to do the part that hides the TextView object. Hey! Thanks for mentioning TextUtils in your sample code!!! I didn't know about it. I had created my own StringUtil class!!! This I really like the we can so easily customize our views in Android... provided we know how! :-)

Comment: Actually, I was wrong! we do need to set the visibility back!

Answer (score 0):

there is an attribute on textview that lets you control its visibility.
In the xml:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dependentTextViewId"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />
```

Then in your activity java you can set it to visible based on a listener or other conditions

```
TextView tv = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.dependentTextViewId);
            tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Thanks to Tanis for providing the answer on conditionally hiding a TextView
//So the complete solution is to create a custom SimpleAdapter:
public class JournalDisplayListAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
//--- some code skipped here
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    TextView activityGroupName;
    TextView activityDescription;
    if (row != null) {
        activityGroupName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.activityGroupName);
       if (TextUtils.isEmpty(activityGroupName.getText())){
            activityGroupName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       } else {
            activityGroupName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
         }
        activityDescription = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.activityDescription);
       if (TextUtils.isEmpty(activityDescription.getText())){
           activityDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }else {
            activityDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
         }
}

return row;

}
```